# How to call Python function in JavaScript environment on Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to call a Python function from a web page?

Or is there a way inject Python methods to selenium, it can used by JavaScript call.

I was not able to get some message from AJAX request result, if JS can call a Python method.

```py
def test():
   pass
options = Options()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options)
```

```js
// Is there a way call Python test method?
window.test() // ??
```